# SQL Query Select first rank 1 row From Multiple ranks/Group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, dense-rank

I have following data

Table1

```
id   col1    col2       col3
----------------------------------
1    abc   01/01/2012    -
1    abc   01/01/2012    A
2    abc   01/01/2012    -
2    abc   01/02/2012    -
3    abc   01/02/2012    -
3    xyz   01/01/2012    -
4    abc   01/02/2012    -
4    xyz   01/01/2012    -
4    xyz   01/02/2012    -
```

following is order to evaluate -

```
if(col1 is false) then evaluate col2 if(col2 is false) then col3:

Col1 - xyz has first preference from all values in this column
col2 - min date
col3 - not '-' or min(col3)
```

I want to return only one row for each id, if col1 fails go to col2, if this fails then go to col3 condition.
From above table result should be

```
 id   col1    col2       col3
----------------------------------
 1    abc     01/01/2012  A
 2    abc     01/01/2012  -
 3    xyz     01/01/2012  -
 4    xyz     01/01/2012  -
```

I tried using dense rank but it didn't help. I'm not sure how to perform this logic using any available function or sql logic.

```
for col1 - if more than one row for same code or xyz code then fail
for col2 - if more than one row with same min date then fail 
           [use this only if col1 condition fails]
```

Comment: :what do you mean by `preference order for each column:`  ? can you please explain this ,and on what grounds condition fails specific to column?

Comment: updated. I want to check if each column has only one row for specified condition, if it fails then check next column.

Comment: like above what do you mean by "preference" cos by the above example you whant group by ID, max(col1), min(col2), max(col3)

Comment: i want to evaluate col2 condition only when col1 condition fails.

Comment: check rows with id - 3 in table1 and my desired result row id - 3

Comment: xyz is sample text i can have zyx code but i still want xyz (max will return zyx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify many conditions to order by in your analytic function

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id,
               col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               dense_rank() over (partition by id
                                      order by (case when col1 = 'xyz' 
                                                     then 1 
                                                     else 0 
                                                 end) desc,
                                               col2 asc,
                                               col3 asc) rnk
          FROM your_table)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

I'm assuming that you want `dense_rank` given that you used the `dense_rank` tag.  You don't talk about how you want to handle ties or whether ties are even possible, so it's not clear from the question itself whether you want to use the `rank`, `dense_rank`, or `row_number` analytic functions.  If you are only ever fetching the highest ranking row per `id`, `rank` and `dense_rank` will behave identically and will return multiple rows if there are ties for first place.  `row_number` will always return a single row by arbitrarily breaking the tie.  If you want to fetch rows other than the first row per `id`, then you'll need to think about ties and you'll get different behavior from `rank` and `dense_rank`.  If two rows are tied for first, `dense_rank` will assign the third row a `rnk` of 2 while `rank` will assign it a `rnk` of 3.

This seems to work for the sample data you posted

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2  select 1 id, 'abc' col1, to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
  3  select 1 id, 'abc' col1, to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, 'A' col3 from dual union all
  4  select 2 id, 'abc' col1, to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
  5  select 2 id, 'abc' col1, to_date('01/02/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
  6  select 3 id, 'abc' col1, to_date('01/02/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
  7  select 3 id, 'xyz' col1, to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
  8  select 4 id, 'abc' col1, to_date('01/02/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
  9  select 4 id, 'xyz' col1, to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual union all
 10  select 4 id, 'xyz' col1, to_date('01/02/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') col2, null col3 from dual
 11  )
 12  SELECT *
 13    FROM (SELECT id,
 14                 col1,
 15                 col2,
 16                 col3,
 17                 dense_rank() over (partition by id
 18                                        order by (case when col1 = 'xyz'
 19                                                       then 1
 20                                                       else 0
 21                                                   end) desc,
 22                                                 col2 asc,
 23                                                 col3 asc) rnk
 24            FROM x)
 25*  WHERE rnk = 1
SQL> /

        ID COL COL2      C        RNK
---------- --- --------- - ----------
         1 abc 01-JAN-12 A          1
         2 abc 01-JAN-12            1
         3 xyz 01-JAN-12            1
         4 xyz 01-JAN-12            1
```

Comment: this will not work. I want to use col2 rank only when i dont find any one row for col1 rank 1.

Comment: i tried dense rank and it didn't help me much, I'm not looking for sql that uses dense_rank only. i'm trying to figure out if there is another way to implement this.

Comment: @rstech - Have you tried the query I posted?  It certainly seems to work for me.  It will only use `col2` to break the ties in the `col1` condition.

Comment: stupid me! i thought that will not work, but it works on my original data. I somehow was in wrong notion that it will not rank correctly if i use all columns in one order by clause. Thanks

Comment: My only comment is that dense_rank() and rank() return the same results for rank = 1, so the answer should be edited to reflect this.  ("It is not clear from the question whether you want to use rank() or row_number()").

Comment: @GordonLinoff both rank and dense_rank will work. I need only rows with rank 1. dense_rank will not skip numbers after ties which is ok when i partition by id. Let me know if i missed something or i'm wrong

Comment: @rstech . . . I like your answer and even upvoted it.  The way that one sentence is phrased, though, it sounds like dense_rank() and rank() will do different things.  In fact, they do the same thing in this case, so I find that statement almost possibly misleading.  This is just feedback on the phrasing, not on the answer itself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Updated my answer to discuss the differences between the three analytic functions and how they handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

```
with tmp(id, col1, col2, col3, col1b, col3b) as
(select distinct id, col1, col2, col3,
        case when col1 = 'xyz' then '0' else '1' || col1 end,
        case when col3 = '-' then '1' else '0' || col3 end
from Table1)

select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 
from tmp t1
left join tmp t2 on t1.id = t2.id
                and t1.col1b > t2.col1b
left join tmp t3 on t1.id = t3.id
                and t1.col1b = t3.col1b
                and t1.col2 > t3.col2
left join tmp t4 on t1.id = t4.id
                and t1.col1b = t4.col1b
                and t1.col2 = t4.col2
                and t1.col3b > t4.col3b
where t2.id is null
  and t3.id is null
  and t4.id is null
```